# streamingContext can not be resolved to a variable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am doing spark integration with kafka using the following link -

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html

I have added following maven dependency using artifaceId - spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12
Beside this i also added following jars - spark-core_2.12-3.0.1.jar,spark-streaming_2.12-3.0.1.jar

but still getting the error, I am missing some details somewhere like wrong libraries, missing/wrong import, inconsistenies in libraries etc.

IDE - eclipse-jee-oxygen-2-linux-gtk-x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create streamingcontext in order to run the program mentioned in the link.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))
```